# Docker tagging without 'latest' tag?

Tags: docker, amazon-ecr

We've been discussing tagging strategies for our docker ECR repos and what we've landed on doesn't involve use of the `latest` tag at all.

I know `latest` isn't anything automatic. It's just a regular tag. But it's also a convention. Is it expected that `latest` exists? Are there tooling problems or things that may break if our repos don't have it at all?

Comment: Nothing really will break except docker pull <imageName> (without a tag) will return an error since it defaults to the ‘latest’ tag. As long as you always pull with a tag, everything will work just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be fine without the `latest` tag - there should be no tooling problems as long as you are using other tags and / or sha256 digests explicitly for pulling images.

That said, usually there is no good reason to avoid `latest` tag completely. Conventional approach is to push your latest acceptable build to its own tag AND the `latest` tag. It is hard to find an argument against this approach, since using `latest` is convenient in many non-scripted cases (i.e., a developer pulling the image locally and just using `latest`) - and at the same time you get this image with its proper tag.

Final thing I want to mention - since tags may be mutable, scripted pipelines and especially production instances should use explicit sha256 digests when pulling images.